# Cast float to int in Python results wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, floating-point, integer

I have an algorithm that is calculating:

```
result = int(14949283383840498/5262*27115)
```

The correct result should be 77033412951888085, but Python3.8 gives me 77033412951888080

I also have tried the following:

```
>>> result = 77033412951888085
>>> print(result)
77033412951888085
>>> print(int(result))
77033412951888085
>>> print(float(result))
7.703341295188808e+16
>>> print(int(float(result)))
77033412951888080
```

It seems the problem occours when I cast the float to int. What am I missing?

PS: I have found that using `result = 14949283383840498//5262*27115` I get the right answer!

Comment: Floats have limited precision, you're exceeding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting is not the issue. Floating-point arithmetic has limitations with respect to precision. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Need to either use integer division or use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module which defaults to using 28 places in precision.

**Using integer division**

```
result = 14949283383840498 // 5262 * 27115
print(result)
```

Output:

```
77033412951888085
```

**Using decimal module**

```
from decimal import Decimal
result = Decimal(14949283383840498) / 5262 * 27115
print(result)
```

Output:

```
77033412951888085
```

Comment: Thank you! This works!

Answer (score 0):

It is an precision limitation :

```
result = 14949283383840498/5262*27115
result
7.703341295188808e+16
```

In this case, result is a float.
You can see that the precision is of 15 digits.
Convert that to int, you see that the last non zero digit is 8, it is correct to what result: float show when printed.

Try the following:

```
print(sys.float_info.dig)
15
```

dig is the maximum number of decimal digits that can be faithfully represented in a float.

A very good explanation regarding this issue is available [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-sys-float-info-max-min/).

But there are ways to do better with Python, see from the Python's [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> For use cases which require exact decimal representation, try using
> the decimal module which implements decimal arithmetic suitable for
> accounting applications and high-precision applications.
>
> Another form of exact arithmetic is supported by the fractions module
> which implements arithmetic based on rational numbers (so the numbers
> like 1/3 can be represented exactly).
>
> If you are a heavy user of floating point operations you should take a
> look at the NumPy package and many other packages for mathematical and
> statistical operations supplied by the SciPy project